# Vocabulary in Context for the word frivolous

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

In the following article published in 1997, the author considers the possible ramifications of a future where human cloning is a reality.

Excerpt from passage from Princeton Review SAT Practice

> There are other possibilities we could spin out. Suppose a couple wants a 'designer child" a clone of Cindy Crawford and Elizabeth Taylor-because they want a daughter who will grow up to be as attractive as those women. Indeed, suppose someone wants a clone, never mind of whom, simply to enjoy the notoriety of having one. We cannot rule out such cases as impossible. `Some people produce children for all sorts of ***frivolous*** or contemptible reasons.` But we remember that cloning is not as easy as going to a video store. given the physical and emotional burdens that cloning would involve, it is likely that such cases would be extremely rare.

Frivolous most nearly means

A. extravagant

B. Infamous

C. shameful

D. trivial

E. unique

I see how E and A can be wrong. The correct answer is D. I can't choose between B,C, and D. 
Why is D. correct?

Comment: Because that is what *frivolous* means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could technically substitute all of those three words (though I don't think "infamous reasons" sounds natural), but neither "shameful" or "infamous" is a synonym of "frivolous".

"Frivolous" means "lacking seriousness, unimportant" - pretty much the same as "trivial".